# Unexpected result when simply filling an array

Tags: c, array

So, I have been trying to understand this simple code and why it doesn't produce the expected result. Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
double *x;
double *y;
int i;
x =(float*)malloc(11*sizeof(float));
y =(float*)malloc(11*sizeof(float));

for(i=0;i<11;i++)
{
x[i] = (2+pow(10,-i));
y[i] = log(x[i]);
printf("%d : Exp res : %f %f\n",i,x[i],y[i]);
}


printf("\nres : %f %f\n",x[0],y[0]);
return 0;
}
```

And here is what it produces :

[image]

As you can see, it turns out that the values of my y array do not correspond to those calculated in the for loop. The result for the first y value should be 1.098612 and the actual value that is stored is 2.000001. It seems to only happen with the y values since all my x values are correct...

I am probably missing something huge that explains why it doesn't show the right value, but I can't find what it is...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community. We only review code that is working as expected, there are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry about that ! First time posting...

Comment: user253559, Tip: Do **not** size to the type as in `sizeof(float)`. Instead size to the referenced object `sizeof *x` or `sizeof x[0]`.  Also cast not needed: `x = malloc(sizeof x[0] * 11);`. This is more than a style issue, it reduces errors. It is easier to code right, review and maintain. Had your code originally been `sizeof(double)`, I would still suggest it in a review. Tip 2: Post coding problems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/).  Look forward to seeing your corrected code here on a new post. Tip 3: (part of any code review), use an auto formatter to improve its appearance & clarity.

Answer (score 1):

```
double *x;
double *y;
int i;
x =(float*)malloc(11*sizeof(float));
y =(float*)malloc(11*sizeof(float));
```

Your x and y are pointers to doubles, but you are allocating space for 11 floats.
Since floats are smaller than double you are writing over the boundaries of the memory allocated in x and the allocated memory of y happens to be just next to it, so you end up with the values you wrote into the higher value being stored in the first entry of y.

Try allocating enough space for 11 doubles.

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.